# X,Y line offset without self intersection

Tags: c#

I am trying to correct this C# code which should create an offset line without self intersection. It calculates its offset from probed points(x,y coordinates) and an inputted offset distance. The Y offset component works but the X does not. Any help or insight would be infinitely appreciated.
Here is the section of code that executes this process.

```
private void OffsetData(double R)
{
    double Increment = 0.01;
    X2 = (double[])X.Clone();  // copy original

    // apply a circle to every measured point and
    // push neighbor points out beyond the circle
    for (int i = 0; i < Npts; i++)
    {
        // offset forward
        double k = i + Increment;
        while (k < Npts - 1)
        {
            // determine how far away the neighbor is in Y
            double dy = (k - i) * DeltaY;

            // compute extent outward in X
            double d = R * R - dy * dy;
            if (d < 0) break; // beyond circel radius - no need to go further
            double dx = Math.Sqrt(d);

       //interpolate to find X[k] where K is a fraction
       int ki = (int)k;
       double Xk = X[ki] + (X[ki + 1] - X[ki]) * (k - ki);

       // if x value is within circle push out
       if (X2[i] < Xk + dx) X2[i] = Xk + dx;
       k += Increment;
       }
        // offset backward
        k = i - Increment;
        while (k > 0)
        {
            // determine how far away the neighbor is in Y
            double dy = (k - i) * DeltaY;

            // compute extent outward in X
            double d = R * R - dy * dy;
            if (d < 0) break;
```

// beyond circle radius - no need to go further
                double dx = Math.Sqrt(d);

```
       //interpolate to find X[k] where K is a fraction
       int ki = (int)k;
       double Xk = X[ki] + (X[ki + 1] - X[ki]) * (k - ki);

            // if x value is within circle push out
            if (X2[i] < Xk + dx) X2[i] = Xk + dx;
            k -= Increment;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Distance = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)  You have a minus instead of a plus.
#

Comment: Thank you jdweng I will make that adjustment immediately and let you know how I fare. Hope you have a great week!

Comment: Thanks for the help jdweng unfortunately the offset didn't respond as expected to the change. We did resolve the issue although don't understand why the change we made had the effect it did. We simply removed a line of code which gave an initial 0 x,y reference and a space at the end of the code and it worked fine after that. Thanks for your time and hope you have a good one. Cheers!